# Any alternative for Microsoft OneNote in Ubuntu?

Tags: libreoffice

After a major migration from Windows to Ubuntu 12.0.4 Lts, I have found that I can find a substitute for pretty much everything I worked with on Windows 7. the LibreOffice package is an all-out package that can easily meet every requirements and satisfy needs, but there is one thing missing from the equation and that is an application that can open OneNote files with .one extension in  Ubuntu and Kubuntu (Debian). It is a huge hole in there for me to lament about everyday since my students do their homework in OneNote Notebooks, I have to switch to Windows every time, which is like going back to drive a rundown junk car after buying a Mercedes S500 and driving it for a while. it is so dramatically sad. what should I do?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at this [article](http://linuxandfriends.com/note-taking-free-microsoft-onenote-alternatives-for-linux/). Although none is a 100% replacement of onenote functionality, you'll find there are some impressive apps. **tl;dr Here's the  list:**

- [BasKet](http://basket.kde.org/) is a note taking software that has a number of features for taking notes and organizing data.
- [Zim Wiki](http://zim-wiki.org/) – a Desktop Wiki, is a wonderful tool for taking notes. It does not behave anything like any traditional note taking software or Microsoft OneNote. Rather, it works like a wiki.
- [Tomboy](http://projects.gnome.org/tomboy/) is a cool note taking software which is installed by default in many Linux distributions.
- [CherryTree](http://www.giuspen.com/cherrytree/) is a cross platform hierarchical note taking software.
- [MyNotex](http://linuxandfriends.com/mynotex-a-simple-note-taking-software-for-linux/) is an upcoming note taking software in Linux that supports a number of features that are ideal for taking notes.
- [KeepNote](http://rasm.ods.org/keepnote/) is designed to be a general note taking software that can be used in many different ways depending on the user’s needs.
- [TuxCards](http://www.tuxcards.de/) is another note taking software which is quite impressive.
- [Kjots](http://userbase.kde.org/KJots) is a very good note taking software. Recently, it has been rewritten grounds up using Qt 4 libraries. It is very quick to start up in GNOME even though it is essentially a KDE application.
- [RedNotebook](http://linuxandfriends.com/rednotebook-a-very-good-free-journaling-software/) is more of a personal diary and journal than a note taking software.
- A simple note taking software written primarily for GNOME/Gtk-2, [GJots2](http://bhepple.freeshell.org/gjots/) is quite lean in features.
- [Knowit](http://knowit.sourceforge.net/) is a note taking software catering to people who want to store text snippets as notes.
- [NoteCase](http://notecase.sourceforge.net/) is a hierarchical notes manager (Outliner). It supports rich text editing and image insertion.
- [Wixi](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/wixi/index.php?title=Main_Page) – This is a multi-platform wiki application for the desktop. It is written in python/wxpython and uses txt2tags to generate text to many other formats. The goal is to provide a simple wiki tool around the txt2tags document generator and also be multi-platform.
- [Memoranda](http://linuxandfriends.com/memoranda-a-free-personal-diary-and-scheduling-tool/) – This is a free personal diary and scheduling tool. However, it can be used to keep notes. It contains a notes tab which has a rich text editor built-in. You can insert images and use different styles of text as well.

If none of these covers your needs, there is the last resort of installing and running onenote through wine. I have read reports of success for the 2007 version but I have no idea about how the newer versions fare in that respect.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the solution I'm using so far.  It's not perfect, but it lets me view most of the stuff in OneNote from ubuntu.

I have a Microsoft Live account and I have all my OneNote notebooks on my skydrive.  You can login to live.com and look at your skydrive and open up your OneNote notebooks.

To review your student's work, you'd need to move them to your skydrive first and depending on your storage, that may be limited.

The one problem with using the web interface is that I'm not sure if it's possible to insert a file onto a page or take advantage of the 2013 feature that allows you to insert an Excel file and have each sheet displayed as an image which you can then click on to edit.  The images still display in the OneNote web interface, but you can't edit them.

As long as you aren't inserting files/objects...the web interface is OK for reviewing and adding new notes and images.

Search isn't as good as it only allows you to search one section at a time instead of all notebooks.

Answer (score 2):

Use evernote by installing nevernote client.  Best available.  They support everything natively except Ubuntu and that is why you use the nevernote client.

Otherwise, the web client is so advanced, it is better than a lot of the competitors apps.